# Optimizing code - traversing 2 list objects

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 List `allCarOwners: CarOwner[] = [];` and `selectedCarOwners: CarOwner[] = [];`

**CarOwner Model**

```
carId
ownerName
carType
carYear
```

The `allCarOwners` list will contain around 600k+ records, and the `selectedCarOwners` will contain around 500K+ records in it. I need to compare the 2 `carId` 's from the 2 list and update the `ownerName` field in the `allCarOwners` list. I will ulso be updating the UI.

```
        this.allCarOwners.map((allCarOwner: CarOwner , index) => {
          this.selectedCarOwners.map((selectedCarOwner: CarOwner ) => {
            if (allCarOwner.carId=== selectedCarOwner.carId) {
                 // Update
            }
         });
        });
```

The problem I am facing is that the browser stops responding for awhile, since there's 600K and 500K records when looping the 2 list. Is there a way I could write this logic in a better way ? Can I run this is Multiple threads (using `ParalelForeach`).

Please help me out ?

Comment: I think you should take a huge step back and wonder if it's a good idea to manipulate lists of 600K elements in a web frontend application. That logic should be in your backend. But anyway, your code is O(n^2). Make it O(n) by storing the selected car owner in a Map where the key is the var ID. A map lookup if O(1).

Comment: Adding on to @JBNizet 's point, I would recommend you to do some kind of server side pagination/filtering so that only a certain number of rows is being fetched at any one time. On top of that, you should consider virtual scrolling to minimise the negative performance on your DOM.

Comment: adding to first comment. also you can try to use WebWorkers for this operation